# how to reset count in foreach loop in php?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

looking at my example, what i am trying to do is to make sure that there is no `null` result

basically, foreach $array, if $xxx[$key] is null, restart the assignment from the start

below, i am hardcoding $k, $v and $y, but i don't know how big `$array` is so i cant just loop like this forever.

any ideas how to simplify this? It would be great if the `foreach` is on `$array` and not use for loops

```
$xxx = ['a','b'];
$array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
$k = 0;
$v = 0;
$y = 0;
foreach($array as $key =>  $val){
    if(isset($xxx[$key])){
        var_dump($xxx[$key]);
    } else {
        if(isset($xxx[$k])){
            var_dump($xxx[$k]);
        } else {
            if(isset($xxx[$v])){
                var_dump($xxx[$v]);
            } else {
                var_dump($xxx[$y]);
                $y++;
            }
            $v++;
        }
        $k++;
    }
}
```

result:

```
string 'a' (length=1)
string 'b' (length=1)
string 'a' (length=1)
string 'b' (length=1)
string 'a' (length=1)
string 'b' (length=1)
string 'a' (length=1)
string 'b' (length=1)
null
```

Comment: `$size = count($array)` won't tell you how big the array is? and diffing the keys of both arrays would tell you which keys they have in common, e.g. `$diff = array_diff(array_keys($xxx), array_keys($array))`

Comment: so, `1` would be assigned to `a`, then `2` to `b`, then `3` and `4` should be assigned to `a` and `b` respectively, and so on

Comment: What's the expected result? An array with 1 => a, 2 => b, 3 => a, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the mod operator instead, that way it goes on indefinitely no matter the size of $array or $xxx.

```
$xxx = ['a','b','c','d'];
$array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    var_dump($xxx[$key % count($xxx)]);
}
```

print out:

```
string(1) "a" 
string(1) "b" 
string(1) "c" 
string(1) "d" 
string(1) "a" 
string(1) "b" 
string(1) "c" 
string(1) "d" 
string(1) "a"
```

Answer (score 0):

roll up your own function to check whether an item value is null or not then pass or set its value pass it as a callback function to [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) or [array_walk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) to check out the values, so you get the callback:

```
array_walk($data, function(&$item, $key) {

  if ( $item === null ) {
    $item = something;
    // or do something else
  }
});
```